# how to monitor cpu instruction being called by a program

Tags: c, x86

how to monitor cpu instruction being called by a program.

Comment: I really don't think thats possible.

Comment: What do you mean? Get a list of instructions? Get a count of instructions? Monitor a specific instruction?

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the platform, you might be able to run the program under a debugger, and single step through the assembly instructions to see exactly what it's doing.

Comment: if you can tell how to develop such a debugger - i am looking to proceed in windows.

Comment: @varun: That's a huge topic, generally best explained in a semester-long university course.  But Visual Studio includes a debugger, so that would be a good place to start learning.

Answer (score 0):

try [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/odbg110.zip)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Matthieu: That's true, I was new on SO at that time tough ;)